# getimagesize function doesn't return anything

Tags: php

I am using php function getimagesize(). It does work in almost all condition but it doesn't work for a particular url. Please help me why isn't it working for that url. Below you can check that url:

```
getimagesize('https://marketdataresearch.credit-suisse.com/cs/mdr/p/s/framework10/img/logo_cs.gif');
```

It returns nothing and not giving any error.

Comment: What does it give if you do a vardump on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific URL actually has some rudimentary security behind it. If you use curl to fetch that URL you will see the following location header:

`Location: /cookie-check?trg=insanely-long-strong`

When you follow that, you just end up on a regular HTML page. What you're trying to do won't be possible without fetching the cookie, using the cookiejar in a curl request, downloading the file, and running `getimagesize` against the local file.

Comment: thanx for your reply, is there any other method to resize this image except that downloading with curl?

Comment: @munjal you could download it using the curl library for PHP (not the command line app), or possibly the PHP stream wrappers. The problem is that the image is protected via a site specific cookie/referer scheme. Implementing it would be one time use, so unless you're going to be pulling images from credit suisse regularly I would just recommend downloading the image by hand and running `getimagesize` on that. If you do decide to implement it in PHP (the download portion), see the documentation for `curl_setopt` and specifically look at the `COOKIEJAR` and `COOKIEFILE` options. Good luck!